# Handle NullPointerException with SeekBar

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am receiving a `NullPointerException` sometimes with my SeekBar.

I am learning Android, and I am not able to find the proper way to fix this error.

**I am using the below code for the `onStopTrackingTouch` SeekBar:**

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                setScaledSize(seekBar.getProgress() / 100.f);
            }
```

**And function `setScaledSize` is displayed below:**

```
private void setScaledSize(float scaledSize) {
        mSizeSeekBar.setProgress((int) (scaledSize * 100.0f));
        paintview.setDrawingScaledSize(scaledSize);
    }
```

**I am getting an error like the below log:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.shayari.cardmaker.PaintView.setDrawingScaledSize(float)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.shayari.cardmaker.NameArt.setScaledSize(NameArt.java:767)
                                                                           at com.example.shayari.cardmaker.NameArt.access$200(NameArt.java:78)
                                                                           at com.example.shayari.cardmaker.NameArt$19.onStopTrackingTouch(NameArt.java:708)
                                                                           at android.widget.SeekBar.onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:121)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:772)
                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10063)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
```

**How can I prevent this error?**

Comment: In onStoprackingTouch function, try changing the denominator from 100.f to 100.0f

Comment: @gonephishing. I think its working fine with your solution. Thanks

Comment: I have posted the same as an answer so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    setScaledSize(seekBar.getProgress() / 100.f);
}
```

by changing the denominator from 100.f to 100.0f as follows:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    setScaledSize(seekBar.getProgress() / 100.0f);
}
```